# An adjective which suggests "does not support itself"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective which suggests that the noun it modifies can't support or justify itself, thinking mainly in terms of an argument. There is "self-defeating", but this isn't the sense I'm looking for. I don't want to suggest that the argument has proved itself *wrong*, but rather it has failed to prove itself *right*.

E.g.

> A.J. Ayer's verification principle is [failing to support itself] because the statement "Only verifiable statements are meaningful" is not itself verifiable."

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "failing to support or justify itself". Could you provide an example of a principle that does what you're saying the verification principle doesn't? I don't expect principles to prove *themselves*. Saying that it doesn't apply to itself seems like it'd be more appropriate.

Comment: There is no point in using a single-word adjective in the first place. You are trying to shoehorn the meaning of an entire phrase into an obscure word rather than just saying what you have to say in a manner understandable by everyone.

Comment: @Rupe, that's a fair comment, though - without getting too far into the philosophy because it's certainly OT - if a principle says that *all* statements must be verifiable in order to be meaningful, surely the original statement itself shouldn't be exempted?

Comment: @RegDwigнt, I suppose it's a bad habit I've picked up from philosophy; I've grown fond of words that singularly express complex ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A.J. Ayer's verification principle is *inconsistent* because the statement "Only verifiable statements are meaningful" is not itself verifiable."
>
> **inconsistent**: lacking in correct logical relation, as of an argument.

Comment: I think that fits the sentence perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: @LeoKing You're welcome! :-)

Comment: ***[Inconsistent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inconsistent#Adjective)***, which means “not consistent”, is a **wrong answer**. Note that a relevant sense of *[consistent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consistent)* is  “Of a set of statements, such that no contradiction logically follows from them”.  Inconsistent statements are such that a contradiction necessarily follows.  Inconsistency is not failure to prove  something right – as asked for in question – but instead is proof an argument is wrong. -1.

Answer (score 2):

[*Fallible*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3afallible), [*flawed*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3aflawed), or [*unsubstantiated*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3aunsubstantiated).

These are all not quite what you have requested. However, I think an argument inherently cannot support itself; that would be circular reasoning. The above would describe an argument that is insufficiently supported.

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe an argument can only ever be self-defeating, not self-substantiating.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clearer alternative:

> A.J. Ayer's **argument in support of** the verification principle is
>   **unsound** because the **premise** that "Only verifiable statements are meaningful" is not itself verifiable.

Comment: +1 Nice modification, and definitely solves awkward phrasing problems. But, I would have thought the verification principle is the argument itself, which is why I didn't write "an argument in support of" originally.

Comment: That makes sense. Well, I still like your answer and would accept it if I had a tick going spare, but Elian's answer supplies a word to the exact format I was trying to write.

Comment: ... Did you delete your comment? It seemed perfectly sound to me.

Comment: I'd say it's the logical *conclusion* of the argument based on certain *premise(s)* - I meant to edit the comment, but deleted it by accident.

Comment: Oh okay. Well cheers, I always appreciate the people who go beyond the scope of the question (even if SE don't.)

Answer (score 2):

**Receptary**:  admitted as fact but unproven

Answer (score 0):

> ...but rather it has failed to prove itself right.

Is there an example of a statement that does prove itself right? I'd suggest almost all statements don't.

[Self-refuting idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea)

> Self-refuting ideas or self-defeating ideas are ideas or statements whose falsehood is a logical consequence of the act or situation of holding them to be true.